# Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I must be blind or tired. I can not find the source of the error
The error is "Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected end of file" and references the last line number of my code. What am I missing. Also any general PHP tips for the code would also be welcomed. I am only 8 weeks into learning PHP through a college course

```
    <?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
    <?php require('../model/database.php');?>

    <?php

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');


    if ($email == '')
    {   
     $error = 'Email cannot be blank. Please enter a valid email.';
    require_once('index.php');
   exit();
   }



    $query = 'SELECT customerID, firstName, lastName, email
        FROM customers
        WHERE email = :email';
    
 $statement = $db->prepare($query);
 $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement->execute();
$customer = $statement->fetch();
$statement->closeCursor();


if ($customer['email'] != $email)
{
$error = 'No matching email. Please enter a valid email.';

require_once('index.php');
exit();
}


$query = 'SELECT productCode
        FROM products
        ORDER BY productCode';
    
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$productCodes = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

?>

<main>
<h2>Register Product</h2>

    <p></p>    
    <form action="product_registered.php" method="post" id="aligned">            
        <input type="hidden" name="customerID"
            value="<?php echo $customer['customerID']; ?>">     

        <label>Customer:</label>
        <label><?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['firstName'] . ' ' . $customer['lastName']); ?></label>
        <br>

        <label>Product:</label>
        <select name="productCode">
            <?php foreach ($productCodes as $productCode): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($productCode['productCode']); ?>">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($productCode['name']); ?>
            </option>
        </select>
        <br>                        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>           
        <input type="submit" value="Register Product" /><br>            
    </form>
</main>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

(1) You have `<?php foreach ($productCodes as $productCode): ?>`, but you are missing `endforeach;`

So, add the following line after the line `</option>`

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

(2) Did you fetch `name` data ? Since you want to use `$productCode['name']` in the following line

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($productCode['name']); ?>
```

So change the line:

```
$query = 'SELECT productCode FROM products ORDER BY productCode';
```

to

```
$query = 'SELECT productCode, name FROM products ORDER BY productCode';
```

Comment: YES!!! OMG totally forgot about the closing the foreach. Thank you!!
Also correct on the 'name' field